# Python: faster way to do Geocoding API

Tags: python, google-geocoding-api

It almost takes 1 mimute to convert 60 addresses to coordinates with my code. I want the result to contain address, latitude and longtitude in order. Is there other faster ways? Thanks

code:

```
import time
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

addressList=['xxx','xx1'] #330,000 addresses in total

def get_latitude_longtitude(address, GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY): 
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=' + GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY
    while True:
        res = requests.get(url)
        js = json.loads(res.text)

        if js['status'] != 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT':   
            time.sleep(1) 
            break

    result = js['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
    lat = result['lat'] 
    lng = result['lng'] 

    return address, lat, lng

lst=[]
for address in addressList:
    GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY = 'kkkkkkk'
    res = get_latitude_longtitude(address,GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY)
    #print(res)
    address=res[0]
    lat=res[1]
    lng=res[2]
    lst.append(address)
    lst.append(lat)
    lst.append(lng)
```

Comment: You could start writing parallel/async code to fire off several requests at once; but I'd expect to get rate limited by the API for that sooner or later…

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) (or similar) to run a fixed number of processes in parallel, then have each process send requests at a fixed rate (e.g. 1 request per second), and thus adjusting the number of processes you can adjust the overall request rate.

Google Maps Platform APIs have default usage limits, see
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis

If you intend on going *as fast as possible*, see also the [Best Practices Using Directions API Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/web-service-best-practices) and in particular the **Polite Use of Google APIs** section. TL;DR: if you try to go *too fast* you'll end up going *slower* (due to retries).